# How to create migration for smart contract with Struct Array in constructor

Tags: truffle, struct, constructor

I have a smart contract that has the following Struct Array in its `constructor`:

```
struct Details {
        string tokenType;
        address tokenAddress;
        uint256 tokenId;
        uint256 amount;
}

constructor(Details[] memory _details)
```

How do I create the `migration.js` for it?

I know I have to pass the arguments for it as a second parameter on the `deployer.deploy` function, but I don't know how `truffle` recognizes, for example, the `address` type in the Struct since it is not Solidity but JavaScript:

```
const SmartWallet = artifacts.require("SmartWallet");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SmartNFTFactory);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is as follows:

```
const SmartWallet = artifacts.require("SmartWallet");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SmartNFTFactory, [["ERC20", "0xfe02781cc0fe76Bfd2D211430bfa97D2889fd853", 0, 0]]);
};
```

The second argument for the `deploy` function is the `Details[]` array that the smart contract expects.

If you have any extra doubt, here is a [link](https://github.com/MatiFalcone/struct-array-constructor) to a `hardhat` project that implements a very simple functionality to show how this may work.

Answer (score 1):

Alright hopefully last edit haha I didn't see that it was an array so I appologize.

I wrote a little sample contract to show you how to do the constructor, since you cannot pass an array of structs as a function param.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract TEST {
    // declare struct
    struct Details {
        string tokenType;
        address tokenAddress;
        uint256 tokenId;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    // create mapping to store structs by their address
    mapping(address => Details) public tokenDetails;
    // or ID
    // mapping(uint256 => Details) public tokenDetails;

    // Pass array of each value into constructor
    constructor(
        string[] memory _tokenTypes,
        address[] memory _tokenAddresses,
        uint256[] memory _tokenIds,
        uint256[] memory _tokenAmounts
    ) {
        // make sure all arrays are the same length
         require(
            _tokenTypes.length == _tokenAddresses.length &&
                _tokenTypes.length == _tokenIds.length &&
                _tokenTypes.length == _tokenAmounts.length,
            "Array length mismatch"
        ); 
        // loop through arrays and add each value to mapping
        for (uint256 i; i < _tokenTypes.length; i++) {
            tokenDetails[_tokenAddresses[i]].tokenType = _tokenTypes[i];
            tokenDetails[_tokenAddresses[i]].tokenAddress = _tokenAddresses[i];
            tokenDetails[_tokenAddresses[i]].tokenId = _tokenIds[i];
            tokenDetails[_tokenAddresses[i]].amount = _tokenAmounts[i];
        }
    }
}
```

and then for the migrations you would set it up like this :

```
const SmartWallet = artifacts.require("SmartWallet");
    
module.exports = function(deployer) {
   const tokenTypes = ["foo","bar"];
   const tokenAddresses = ["0x1234..","0x5678..."];
   const tokenIds = [0,1];
   const amounts = [10000, 10001];
   deployer.deploy(SmartNFTFactory, tokenTypes, tokenAddresses, tokenIds, amounts);
};
```

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I am asking. I am asking about the migration file in truffle for that contract.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you how to use the constructor arguments in migrations! Hope that was what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you! But do you see that the constructor of the smart contract expects only one argument with an array? How do I pass that to the contract? It is a an array of structs.

Comment: alright hopefully final edit now that I understand your question better, my apologies but hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Are you sure you cannot pass and array of structs as a constructor now? Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71558241/passing-a-struct-array-to-constructor-of-solidity-contract. The last comment says that you can do it with Solidity 0.8.9. I also have a contract myself and it compiles with no problems.

Comment: I tried doing a test to pass an array of structs and I couldn't get it to work correctly, I'll try again and get back to you but I read a bunch of posts that say it's not supported.